# OpenEMM calls nonexistent logon.do method

Tags: javascript, linux, tomcat, servlets, centos

Running Tomcat 8.0 on a Centos 6 server -- trying to install OpenEMM.

When I try to access the login page from the index page on Tomcat I get a 404. I have discovered that login.jsp simply redirects to login.do?action=0. However, there is no .do routine listed in the logon.jsp file. Direct access to the logon.jsp file returns the following:

> type Exception report
>
> message An exception occurred processing JSP page /logon.jsp at line
>   37
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /logon.jsp at line 37
>
> 1: <%-- 2:
>   /********************************************************************************* 3: * The contents of this file are subject to the Common Public
>   Attribution
>
> Stacktrace:
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Module 'null' not found.
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.getModuleConfig(TagUtils.java:755)
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.getModuleConfig(TagUtils.java:735)
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.retrieveMessageResources(TagUtils.java:1098)
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.message(TagUtils.java:956)
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.MessageTag.doStartTag(MessageTag.java:224)
>   org.apache.jsp.logon_jsp._jspx_meth_bean_005fmessage_005f0(logon_jsp.java:321)
>   org.apache.jsp.logon_jsp._jspService(logon_jsp.java:126)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.0-RC3 logs.

The Tomcat logs contain this:

14-Oct-2013 14:25:51.322 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-1]

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [An
>   exception occurred processing JSP page /logon.jsp at line 37
>
> 1: <%-- 2:
>   /********************************************************************************* 3: * The contents of this file are subject to the Common Public
>   Attribution
>
> Stacktrace:] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException: Module
>   'null' not found. at
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.getModuleConfig(TagUtils.java:755)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.getModuleConfig(TagUtils.java:735)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.retrieveMessageResources(TagUtils.java:1098)
>   at org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.message(TagUtils.java:956) at
>   org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.MessageTag.doStartTag(MessageTag.java:224)
>   at
>   org.apache.jsp.logon_jsp._jspx_meth_bean_005fmessage_005f0(logon_jsp.java:321)
>   at org.apache.jsp.logon_jsp._jspService(logon_jsp.java:126) at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:223)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1010)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:282)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2226)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Line 37 is this (had to delete the html brackets):

> title bean:message key="logon.title" title

When I comment out bean:message the program executes to line 63, which is:

> html:form action="/logon"

I'm scratching my head. Can anybody offer some help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was the version of Tomcat I was using. OpenEMM 2013 requires Tomcat 6. As soon as I removed Tomcat 8 and installed Tomcat 6 the error ceased.